# Apache POI output problem

Tags: java, excel, http, tomcat, apache-poi

I have a problem with Apache POI. I attempt to return a file after I have processed the relevant data. When I go to return the file to the browser(Both IE8/9, firefox), the browser returns a load of garbage characters. This only happens when the Excel file is large and the process has been running for say 2 minutes plus. Otherwise it returns a file which I can then open in Excel.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".xls\"");
OutputStream out = null;

try {
  out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
  wb.write(out);
  out.flush();     
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should specify the content length as well. This is the line you should insert:

```
response.setContentLength(/* length of the byte[] */);
```

I suggest you using Apache Commons IOUtils class for dealing with byte arrays and streams.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what would be the best way to find the length of the stream?

Comment: I can't see the class of `wb` variable. Is that the Workbook? In that case I suggest: 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(bos);
    response.setContentLength(bos.size());
    response.getOutputSream().write(bos.toByteArray());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();